# Erasing a PC disk before selling the machine

Tags: hard-drive

I made a deal with someone over text about selling a computer I had. At first he was going to buy it in good condition, but I spilled water over it. He still wanted it. I assume he wants it for scrap, but I'm afraid he/she is going to use it to make it work again and steal my information, including my personal bank accounts. There is a password on it, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Note that spilling water over a PC does not necessarily kill it. Have you tried booting it up since it dried out? Also, you can always dismount the drive, temporarily attach it to another machine, and wipe it there;  a cable to temporarily attach a laptop drive via YsB us a useful thing and costs about US$20.

Comment: Nobody buys a computer for the scrap metal value.  They plan to use it, repair it, or cannibalize working parts.  You would never want to hand somebody else a drive with sensitive information on the assumption they will just toss it.  But wiping the information is easy enough, and can even be done leaving a working system.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5749/2138) on [security.se] (and some of the other questions linked therein).

Answer (score 5):

Install [DBAN](http://www.dban.org) to USB, boot from it, choose the disk you want to wipe, and wipe it.  If you want to be thorough, you can do several passes, but for the casual user, 1 or 2 passes should be enough.